# Manually Tag People/Faces in Photos for iOS

Tags: ios, mac, icloud, photos

Photos for macOS has the ability to manually tag People in a photo where the machine learning algorithm has not yet detected a Face:

> Window > Info > Add Faces > Click to Name

[image: Click to Name]

These tagged photos then show up when selecting a Person from the People Album in iCloud Photos, just as if they had been recognized by the ML algorithms.

How can I similarly manually tag People/Faces in a photo from the **iOS** Photos app?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot manually tag a face in the current version of iOS.

This function is only available on macOS.