# Problem adding people to the People album

Tags: iphone, photos, album

I have an iPhone XR running iOS 16.2. The [official Apple advice](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207103) for how to add a person to the People album is as followsL:

```
Open a photo of the person you want to add.
Tap the Info button , then tap the face of the person with a question mark.
Tap Tag With Name and type the person's name or tap the name if it shows up.
Tap Next, then tap Done.
```

But when I opened the photo and tap the Info button I'm not getting a question mark or a tiny thumbprint either. The photo simply appears as it is. So my question is how can I add a person to my People album. I've done this successfully before with other people, for whom I was getting the question mark. But now I'm not getting it. Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

If it's of any relevance, I don't use iCloud or any other cloud services.

Comment: The issue is that iOS is not detecting their face, so you have to add it manually. But adding a face manually is not available on iOS, only macOS: [Manually Tag People/Faces in Photos for iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421334/manually-tag-people-faces-in-photos-for-ios)

Comment: I think that is mistaken though. The Apple advice for iPhone (linked in the question) doesn't mention MacOS. I have tagged photos before on the iPhone with people's names and successfully put them in the People album, without MacOS being involved. I have got the little question mark on face photos before. Now I am not getting it.

Comment: That was probably because iOS was able to see it's a face but doesn't recognize who it is; then the procedure you linked to works.